# multiple form actions with one submit button

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to ask about "multiple form actions with one submit button" 
The form actions will be 2 places, Zoho CRM and Google form.

I have tested but the lead didn't save and can't go to thank you page.

I'm not sure if change to this script is correct or not:

```
 function SubmitForm()
    {
        if(document.forms['leadform'].onsubmit())
        {
            showResultDiv();
            document.forms['leadform'].action='https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm';

            document.forms['leadform'].submit();

            document.forms['leadform'].action='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScQzsovLE8zusA88V7VTKQ5ACVYkbg0PWQmTsPd1NKGum8Tsw/formResponse';

            document.forms['leadform'].submit();

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think that onsubmit will return a Boolean result?

Comment: I find the reference here: http://form.guide/web-form/submit-form-multiple-scripts.html, but yes, it is not working...

Comment: I see no example on that page where they are referencing the return of onsubmit() ?

Comment: First off....use the dom, get the form:  var frm = document.getElementById("leadform");  check that it returns correctly, then use frm.setAttribute("action", ...); do not set attributes the way you are doing it.

Answer (score -1):

The type of button is submit:

`<input class="button" type="submit" value=">> Submit" onclick="javascript: return SubmitForm()">`

I think the `SubmitForm()` will never be executed. the form has been submitted,and go to another page.

**EDIT:**

I guess that you are a freshman for web development. [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) can help you know about `<form>` and `<input type='submit'>`

Comment: Thanks! yes, my mistake. after changed, it is not working too. I'm not the programmer.. so I found some reference online, the one I tried is here: form.guide/web-form/submit-form-multiple-scripts.html

Comment: @TraceYan oh! I think it is really a troublesome job to you. The two actions: `https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm` and `https://docs.google.com/forms/...`, which will save the lead, and which will show the [thank you page]?